# Next.js gives missing script on all npm run commands

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am creating a Next.js project as I follow along in a Udemy class. I have the following package.json

```
{
  "name": "nextjsdemo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "^9.0.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6"
  }
}
```

My directory structure is as follows below.

[image]

```
npm install --save next react react-dom
```

When I run the command

```
npm run dev
```

I receive the error:

```
npm ERR! missing script: dev
```

I receive a similar error on npm run build as well.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Thanks,

**Edit 1**
The only way I could get this to work was to downgrade next to V4.2.3. This seems strange that the latest version does not work.

Comment: what `npm` version do u have? `npm --v`

Comment: npm version 6.4.1

Comment: I couldn't think of any possible defect where `npm` wont be able to see an existing script. it also didn't make sense the downgrading `next`'s version solved this, I've just created a new project with the same `package.js` you have and it worked as expected.

Comment: Are you running the script from the root of the project?

Comment: I did run the script from the root of the project

Comment: Like @SultanH. , I was able to get it to work properly too.  Must be an environment issue?

Comment: I will try it again from an empty directory - very strange

Comment: was you able to figure this out?!

Comment: It worked when I followed the setup on https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#setup. No idea why it didn't work in following along with the course. Perhaps it was the nested index files though that really does not make sense. Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 4):

The problem might be your file structure. Try and check if you are in the same folder that holds the package.json file. A common mistake is to have a parent folder (say user/next-demo) that then holds a child folder with your nextJs project (say user/next-demo/next-demo) and then trying to run the next scripts in the parent folder.

Comment: that is true, when you create your app you should change your directory to the directory of the created app, it is mentionned in documentation