# Next server constantly crashing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I created a project to consume a REST api in NEXT, I have two screens with methods to insert, delete and change, one of the screens only use text-type inputs, and it works normally with (Formik and Yup).

when I created the second screen that has a (Select) that I implemented without knowing anything about the component, the server now crashes constantly. Below is the Log with error and the Form component that has the select, I believe it is some basic error in this component.

```
I already deleted the node folders and updated npm
```

LOG

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'next',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.12
3 info using node@v14.16.1
4 verbose stack Error: missing script: next
4 verbose stack     at run (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:155:19)
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:63:5
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:116:5
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:436:5
4 verbose stack     at checkBinReferences_ (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:391:45)
4 verbose stack     at final (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:434:3)
4 verbose stack     at then (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:161:5)
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:382:12
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:123:16
4 verbose stack     at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:63:3)
5 verbose cwd C:\Users\Hugo\Documents\Next\teste
6 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19041
7 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "next" "start"
8 verbose node v14.16.1
9 verbose npm  v6.14.12
10 error missing script: next
11 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

COMPONENT

```
import {
    Button,
    Container,
    createStyles,
    IconButton,
    makeStyles,
    Paper,
    TextField,
    Theme,
    Typography,
    Snackbar,
    Select,
    MenuItem, 
  } from '@material-ui/core';
  import ArrowBackIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowBack';
  import { useFormik } from 'formik';
  import Link from 'next/link';
  import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
  import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
  import * as Yup from 'yup';
  import Layout from '../screen/layouts/layout';
  import Loading from '../screen/loading/form';

  import {vendaById, vendaUpdate, vendaInsert} from '../api/vendas';
  import {vendedoresList} from '../api/vendedores'
  
  const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
    createStyles({
      toolbar: {
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
      },
      form: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
        padding: theme.spacing(3),
      },
      submit: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
      },
    })
  );
  
  interface IFormData {
    valor?: string;
    comissao?: string;
    vendedor_id?: string;
    id?: number;
  }

  
  export default function Venda() {

    const classes = useStyles();
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('Nova Venda');
    const router = useRouter();
    const { id } = router.query;
    const [vendedores, setVendedores] = useState([]);

    const initialValues: IFormData = {
      valor: '',
      comissao: '',
      vendedor_id: '',
      id: '',
    }
  
    const formSchema = Yup.object().shape({
      valor: Yup.string().required('Obrigatório'),
      comissao: Yup.string().required('Obrigatório'),
      vendedor_id: Yup.string().required('Obrigatório')
    });
  
    const formik = useFormik({
      initialValues: initialValues,
      validationSchema: formSchema,
      onSubmit: (values) => {
        console.log(values);
        setTimeout(() => {
          if (id) {
            vendaUpdate(values).then((row) => {
              setMessageInfo({ show: true, message: row.data.message });
              formik.setSubmitting(false);
            });
          }else{
            vendaInsert(values).then((row) => {
              setMessageInfo({ show: true, message: row.data.message });
              formik.setSubmitting(false);
            });
          }
        }, 3000);
      },
    });
  
    useEffect(() => {
      if (id) {
        vendaById(Number(id)).then((row) => {
          setTitle(`Editando a venda: ${row.id}`);
          formik.setValues({
            valor: row.valor,
            comissao: row.comissao,
            vendedor_id: row.vendedor_id,
            id: row.id,
          });
        });
      }

      vendedoresList().then((row) => {
        setVendedores(row);
      });

    }, [id]);

    const [messageInfo, setMessageInfo] = useState<{
      show: boolean;
      message: string;
    }>({ show: false, message: '' });

  
    return (
      <Layout>
        <Container>
          <div className={classes.toolbar}>
            <Link href="/vendas" passHref>
              <IconButton aria-label="Voltar">
                <ArrowBackIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </Link>
            <Typography component="h1" variant="h4">
              {title}
            </Typography>
          </div>
  
          <Paper className={classes.form} elevation={3}>
            <form noValidate onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                margin="normal"
                fullWidth
                id="valor"
                label="Valor"
                name="valor"
                autoComplete="valor"
                autoFocus
                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                value={formik.values.valor}
                error={formik.touched.valor && Boolean(formik.errors.valor)}
                helperText={formik.touched.valor && formik.errors.valor}
              />
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                margin="normal"
                fullWidth
                id="comissao"
                label="Comissão %"
                name="comissao"
                autoComplete="comissao"
                autoFocus
                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                value={formik.values.comissao}
                error={formik.touched.comissao && Boolean(formik.errors.comissao)}
                helperText={formik.touched.comissao && formik.errors.comissao}
              />

              <Select 
                variant="outlined"
                fullWidth
                id="vendedor_id"
                label="Vendedor"
                name="vendedor_id"
                autoComplete="vendedor_id"
                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                value={formik.values.vendedor_id}
                error={formik.touched.vendedor_id && Boolean(formik.errors.vendedor_id)}>
                <MenuItem value="">Selecione</MenuItem>
                  {vendedores.map((row) => (  
                    <MenuItem key={row.id} value={row.id} >{row.nome}</MenuItem>
                  ))}
              </Select>

              <Button
                className={classes.submit}
                type="submit"
                size="large"
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
                disabled={formik.isSubmitting}
              >
                Salvar
              </Button>
              {formik.isSubmitting && <Loading />}
            </form>
          </Paper>
        </Container>
        <Snackbar
              anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'bottom', horizontal: 'center' }}
              autoHideDuration={3000}
              open={messageInfo.show}
              message={messageInfo.message}
              key={messageInfo.message}
          />    
      </Layout>
    );
  }
```

Comment: I'm beginner, try learn NextJS, thanks for help!

Comment: Looks like you still have to install the node modules after you removed them, judging by "Error: missing script: next", which is what is executed when running `npm run dev`. Could you verify that you have run `npm install` or `yarn`?

Comment: Here is a similar question also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57117846/next-js-gives-missing-script-on-all-npm-run-commands

Comment: Also make sure your CLI is in the correct folder (the one that holds package.json)